# Bring Layer panel from header back to the context menu area or lock it opened?

Tags: interface, grease-pencil, viewlayers

In Blender 2.9 the grease pencil layer panel appears on the header and it shows up only when you click on it and disappear when you move the cursor elsewhere. While in the tutorials from Blender 2.8 it is located between the outliner and the context menu and it is always displayed. Which is very comfortable. So I wonder, can I bring it back to the side? Or at least lock the panel so it stays visible while I'm working? [image]

Answer (score 1):

On the side bar (properties), there is a green icon above the material icon, inside that you will find the layers.

[image]